# Checkbox selected even after displaying error message

Tags: javascript

a, b, c, d are 4 checkboxes. If 'a' is selected, then remaining checkboxes b,c,d should not be selected.

If one or more checkbox of b,c,d is selected, then 'a' should not be selected

```
if(document.getElementById('a').checked) {
  if(document.getElementById('b').checked || document.getElementById('c').checked || document.getElementById('d').checked){
    alert("choose between 'A' and one/more option from b,c,d");
    return;
  }
}
```

I am getting an alert message but as soon as I remove the alert , I can see 'a' and one option from b,c,d checked.
How do I prevent it so that only one of them is checked even after I remove the alert message?and  i wanted latest option to be unchecked

Comment: i think its either just a, or bc, cd, bd...etc

Answer (score 1):

I think you should think more about how it would best provide a better user experience. From what I gathered, radio buttons with checkboxes as sub options would fit this case better. Check out the example below.

```js
function handleOption(myRadio) {
  document.querySelectorAll("#bcdCheckboxes input[type='checkbox']").forEach(e => e.disabled = myRadio.value === 'a');
}
```

```css
.indent {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="option" onclick="handleOption(this)" value="a">Option A
<br>
<input type="radio" name="option" onclick="handleOption(this)" value="bcd">Other Options
<br>
<div class="indent" id="bcdCheckboxes">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="b" disabled>Option B</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="c" disabled>Option C</label>
  <br>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="d" disabled>Option D</label>
</div>
```

Comment: what if i wanted latest option to be unchecked

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('b').checked = false;
document.getElementById('c').checked = false;
document.getElementById('d').checked = false;
```

Comment: what if i wanted latest option to be unchecked

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the `checked` property to `false` in the function

```
if(document.getElementById('a').checked) {
        if(document.getElementById('b').checked || document.getElementById('c').checked || document.getElementById('d').checked){
            alert("choose between 'A' and one/more option from b,c,d");
            document.getElementById('b').checked = document.getElementById('c').checked = document.getElementById('d').checked = false
            return;
        }
```

}

[**Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLJBNw)

Comment: what if i wanted latest option to be unchecked